# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS can't connect to the wireless network (QCA9377)

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I am new to Linux and I recently installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.2 dual system. In Windows 10, Wi-Fi works but in Ubuntu, it doesn't. In the settings, it shows "can't find Wi-Fi adapter". Now I have to use a USB connection to the network.

Network card model:
Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)

Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
Controller (rev 10)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

after I type "make", the terminal comes this:

```
/home/l/backports-20151120/backport-include/linux/kconfig.h:25:28: warning: "config_enabled" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
 #define IS_BUILTIN(option) config_enabled(option)
                            ^
```

There is some info about the network card.

```
dmesg | grep ath10k_pci
[   10.867824] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   11.205511] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901
[   11.205513] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   11.205864] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[   12.615138] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[   13.106008] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   13.861392] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
lspci -k
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
```

Any help would be a lot appreciated.